# WPF Label is blank when multibinding with Template

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a Label with a template and I am trying to do multibinding but the label is empty when used in conjunction with Template

Following is the code for Label

```
        <Label Template="{StaticResource SmallHeaderTemplate}" Margin="0,10,5,0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"  >
            <Label.Style>
                <Style>
                    <Setter Property="TextBlock.Text">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} {1}">
                                <Binding Source="{x:Static res:Strings.Val1}"></Binding>
                                <Binding Source="{x:Static res:Strings.Val2}"></Binding>
                            </MultiBinding>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>

                </Style>
            </Label.Style>
        </Label>
```

and Template is

```
   <ControlTemplate x:Key="SmallHeaderTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
        <StackPanel SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
            <TextBlock Foreground="#FF0072C6" FontSize="20"  FontWeight="Regular" FontFamily="Segoe UI Light"  Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" Margin="2,7,2,5" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" />
            <Border Height="1" Margin="0,0,0,5">
                <Border.Background>
                    <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,0">
                        <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="#FFFCFCFC" />
                        <GradientStop Offset="0.5" Color="#FFD7D7D7" />
                        <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="#FFFCFCFC" />
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Border.Background>
            </Border>
        </StackPanel>
    </ControlTemplate>
```

I also tried following for Label but no luck

```
    <Label Template="{StaticResource SmallHeaderTemplate}" Margin="0,10,5,0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"  >
            <Label.Content>
                <TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock.Text>
                            <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} {1}">
                        <Binding Source="{x:Static res:Strings.Val1}"></Binding>
                        <Binding Source="{x:Static res:Strings.Val2}"></Binding>
                    </MultiBinding>
                        </TextBlock.Text>
                </TextBlock>
            </Label.Content>
        </Label>
```

Can anyone give me a hint why this is not working?

Comment: The Text property of the TextBlock in the Label's Template is bound to the Label's Content property, but the Label Style sets `TextBlock.Text`. That doesn't seem to make sense. The Style should set the Content property instead.

Comment: And when you have `<TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>` in the Template, you can of course not set Content to another TextBlock. The only valid Content is a string.

Comment: @Clemens I have tried setting the Content Property by `Label.Content` but result is same. Also, tried removing `Text="{TemplateBinding Content}"` and same issue.

Comment: Sorry, MultiBinding  with StringFormat only works when the target property is of type string. You should have seen Binding error messages in the Output Window in Visual Studio. You may use a MultiBinding Converter instead.

Comment: @Clemens Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your text block is template binding to Content (from label). Label Content is never set though (disregarding your 3rd block of code which sets it to a TextBlock - not a string but an actual TextBlock).

So, set the label Content. You can only use StringFormat with strings (Label.Content is not a string). So, use a converter to do the formatting (MultiBinding in this case).

Here is a working example:
XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp34.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:res="clr-namespace:WpfApp34.Statics"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp34"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<Window.Resources>
    <local:MyConverter x:Key="MyConverter" />
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="SmallHeaderTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
        <StackPanel SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
            <TextBlock Foreground="#FF0072C6" FontSize="20"  FontWeight="Regular" FontFamily="Segoe UI Light"  Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" Margin="2,7,2,5" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" />
            <Border Height="1" Margin="0,0,0,5">
                <Border.Background>
                    <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,0">
                        <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="#FFFCFCFC" />
                        <GradientStop Offset="0.5" Color="#FFD7D7D7" />
                        <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="#FFFCFCFC" />
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Border.Background>
            </Border>
        </StackPanel>
    </ControlTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Label Template="{StaticResource SmallHeaderTemplate}" Margin="0,10,5,0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
        <Label.Content>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MyConverter}" ConverterParameter="{}{0} {1}">
                <Binding Source="{x:Static res:Strings.Val1}" />
                <Binding Source="{x:Static res:Strings.Val2}" />
            </MultiBinding>
        </Label.Content>
    </Label>
</Grid>
```

Code:

```
    using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace WpfApp34
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }

    public class MyConverter : IMultiValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return string.Format(parameter as string, values);
        }

        public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    namespace Statics
    {
        public class Strings
        {
            public static string Val1 { get; set; } = "Val_1";
            public static string Val2 { get; set; } = "Val_2";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about the `IMultiValueConverter` otherwise I did try the above code.